# How to set transparentedit style to a TEdit in firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, android-edittext, delphi-10-seattle

When developing a `Windows` or `iOS` application in **Delphi Seattle 10** we can easily create a transparent `TEdit` by setting it's `StyleLookup` property into `transparentedit`.

However, it doesn't change anything when developing for `Android`.

How do we create a transparent `TEdit` for Android in Firemonkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution - *but solves the problem in a simple way*.

### 1 - Add a blank `TRectangle` to cover up the `Tedit` line. It will look like it is transparent.

*Note : covering it up with 1 px of height will reduce to almost 0 the chances of giving a bad user experience when clicking on the field.*